# Argument of type '() => Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<string>'. ts(2345)

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I'm defining a function that requires an asynchronous function as a parameter:

```js
async function handle(def: Promise<string>) {
    // ...
    const data = await def;
    console.log(`data equals: ${data}`)
}
```

I can succesfully execute this by passing a promise.

```js
handle(new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
    const data = await Promise.resolve("some data")
    if (data == "invalid")
        return rej("data is invalid")
    res(data)
}))
```

I need the inner-function to be async, since I need to perform awaits inside. However, I dislike the async in the promise and read online that [its considered an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43050114/17864167).

I thought it was a better idea to get rid of the promise and use a basic async function:

```js
handle(async () => {
    const data = await Promise.resolve("some data")
    if (data == "invalid")
        throw "data is invalid"
    return data
})
```

But the TS compiler raises the error:

```
Argument of type '() => Promise<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<string>'. ts(2345)
```

I thought that Promises and async functions are somewhat interchangable. I read that async functions [always return a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description). Apperantly I am not interpreting this correctly, but I'm unsure what the error is telling me.

I hope the problem I am sketching is clear. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could clarify the error or give suggestions on how to implement this in the desired way. Big thanks!

Comment: What **exactly** should `def` be? A `Promise<string>` or a function `() => Promise<string>`? Your code says the former but your description says the latter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your function signature seems to be incorrect.
you are defining the parameter to be a `Promise<string>`, while you're really willing it to be `() => Promise<string>`.

```
async function handle(def: () => Promise<string>) {
    // ...
    const data = await def();
    console.log(`data equals: ${data}`)
}
```

Comment: I didn't get the impression that OP wants to change the signature for `handle()`. Also, you need to call `def()` in your answer

Comment: @Phil, well, the parameter is described as `an asynchronous function` above. thanks for the notice

Comment: Not in OP's code it's not... `def: Promise<string>`

Comment: i'm more about the text description above the code snippet

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I had no idea the solution would be so evident. The TS error with `() =>` didn't look familiar and thought the problem was rooted deeper. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the time to use the Promise constructor in a situation like this is right when you call a callback-based function that you want to promisify. But here, it doesn't look like there's anything to promisify, so the Promise constructor doesn't really help.

If

> I need the inner-function to be async, since I need to perform awaits inside.

You can have an immediately invoked async IIFE - yes, using an async callback for the Promise constructor wouldn't be safe, because it wouldn't handle errors.

```
handle((async () => {
    const data = await Promise.resolve("some data")
    if (data == "invalid")
        throw "data is invalid";
    return data
})())
```

The other option is to use `.then` - `.then` is interchangeable with `await` in many situations:

```
handle(
  Promise.resolve("some data")
    .then((data) => {
        if (data == "invalid")
            throw "data is invalid";
        return data;
    })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I have to get more familiar with the .then method, but your example looks 'considering-worthy' to implement.